# Changing background color in Android

Tags: java, android, graphics

I am making an android game and currently I am facing a problem. I want to have a background like the one bellow but the color must be changing constantly.

[image: before]]

My code is:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    changeColors();
    canvas.drawBitmap(ResourcesHandler.mGraphics.getBitmap(bmp), mMatrix, paint);
}
public void changeColors() {
    col[0] += rnd.nextFloat() * .5f;
    if(col[0]>360) col[0]=0;
    paint.setColor(Color.HSVToColor(col));
    paint.setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(Color.HSVToColor(col), 1));
}
```

So, I am changing the color constantly, and i get something like the following image (of course, the color is changing, it's not only red, it become blue, green, violet, etc from time to time but the effect is the same)

[image: after]

 Hope you see the problem. The nice, smooth gradient from the hexagons (first picture), become a wannabe gradient, that is actually composed from 2-3 colors and it looks like it was made in paint(second picture). Why is this? I just want to have a nice gradual changing in color, not like that. Is it because I am changing only the hue(and I don't change saturation for example. which is 1)? Is it because of the filter I use? How can I obtain the effect I want? Btw, you might see that the stroke of the hexagons in the second picture is not really good. That's because it is scaled back and forth 2-3 times. That's not a problem on the actual device(as far as I saw). The problem is only the bad gradient.


  Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English! :)

Comment: I can only barely see the problem you describe, in the pictures you've posted.  I suspect it is a gradient at 60deg from vertical, in each of the hexagons.  I suggest an alternate approach.  Make a beautiful, semi-transparent hexagon and overlay it on alternating background colors...